# Constructing an object that can be iterated using a range based for

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, c++11, iterator

I wrote a short utility function an object to "wrap" an iterable container, so that I could walk it backwards using a range based `for`.

```
template <typename Iterable>
struct ReverseWrapper {
private:
  Iterable& m_iterable;

public:
  ReverseWrapper(Iterable& iterable) : m_iterable(iterable) {}

  auto begin() const ->decltype(m_iterable.rbegin()) {
    return m_iterable.rbegin();
  }

  auto end() const ->decltype(m_iterable.rend()) {
    return m_iterable.rend();
  }
};

template <typename Iterable>
ReverseWrapper<Iterable> reverseIterate(Iterable& list) {
  return ReverseWrapper<Iterable>(list);
}
```

This works for C++ iterable objects, but not for static arrays.  What is required for an object to support iteration using a range based `for`?  What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: +1 I think this would make a useful std component.

Comment: Just call it `reversed` to get a Python-like function :p

Comment: I've edited my answer to improve it with perfect forwarding and functions `rbegin` and `rend` for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual rule to choose `begin` and `end` functions for iterables is the following: use the class `begin` and `end` function if it has some. Use overloads of the global functions [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) if some are provided.

Static arrays not being class/struct, they don't/can't have member functions. The functions called by the foreach loop are the global functions `std::begin` and `std::end`, taking an array as parameter. Assuming `std::rbegin` and `std::rend` existed, you would have to construct your wrapper the following way:

```
template <typename Iterable>
struct ReverseWrapper {
private:
  Iterable& m_iterable;

public:
  ReverseWrapper(Iterable&& iterable) : m_iterable(iterable) {}

  auto begin() const -> decltype(rbegin(m_iterable)) {
    return rbegin(m_iterable);
  }

  auto end() const -> decltype(rend(m_iterable)) {
    return rend(m_iterable);
  }
};

template<typename Iterable>
auto reverseIterate(Iterable&& list)
    -> ReverseWrapper<Iterable>
{
    return ReverseWrapper<Iterable>(std::forward<Iterable>(list));
}
```

Even though [`std::rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [`std::rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend) exist in the c++14 standard, they are not available in the c++11 one. So, to get the above code to work with c++11, you would have to implement these functions by hand:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
auto rbegin(T (&array)[N])
    -> std::reverse_iterator<T*>
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<T*>(std::end(array));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
auto rend(T (&array)[N])
    -> std::reverse_iterator<T*>
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<T*>(std::begin(array));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that `std::rbegin` and `std::rend` exist.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Yeah, I realized it. I'll edit so that readers won't be confused.

Comment: PODs can have member functions, just not virtual ones.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `Iterable` template parameter needs to have `begin` and `end` member functions. Normal C++ arrays do not have those functions. Instead you have to use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), which are part of the C++11 standard.

However, there doesn't seem to be any `std::rbegin` or `std::rend` functions, which means you have to implement those yourself, possibly also implement the actual iterator class.